# CE amplifier circuit gives output voltage that is not completely out of phase

Tags: amplifier, output, phase, common-emitter

[image]
This is the circuit that I have constructed

[image]
But it fails to give the output voltage that is completely inverted (out of phase)

Can anyone show me whats wrong with the circuit?

Comment: Try changing the C1 10 uF and simulate again.

Comment: No. Try changing C2 to 10 times the value or more.

Comment: change the capacitors or frequency.

Answer (score 1):

There are many capacitors you are ignoring, and though most are negligible, one isn't.

Think very hard about what your collector load is. Is it 4k? Is it 1k? Try increasing R5 and go again.

Once that is sorted, you might want to calculate the amount of phase shift the other 10uF capacitors are introducing.

One last capacitor whose effect you won't see until you raise the input frequency is the Miller capacitance of the transistor, between base and collector.